# Making UI changes after calling ConfigureAwait(false) in a webform project

Tags: asp.net, .net, asynchronous, webforms

Can I make UI changes in a webform after calling ConfigureAwait(false)?

```
protected async void btnX_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await myTask();
}

protected async Task myTask() {
  await anotherTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
  lblTaskSuccess.Text = "Success"; // UI Change
}
```

I believe, if SynchronizationContext is UI (e.g. Windows application) then  I won't be able to make UI changes.

Since this is a webform project and SynchronizationContext is aspnet, can I make ui changes (like changing label etc.) or not?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I did try and it worked fine. I'm not sure if it has any other problem.

Comment: I think you could have problem if you try to play with `HttpContext.Current` object after ConfigureAwait(false) as it is attached to a thread.

Comment: To best thing to do is to keep using ConfigureAwait(false) until you find something incompatible. And then for this specific case, use ConfigureAwait(TRUE) instead.

Comment: Does it apply on the event handling function (btnX_onClick)?  If yes, then I should chage it to ```await myTask().ConfigureAwait(false);```

Comment: The configureAwait() method is here to define if the code after await statement should run on the same thread than before call your task. As there are nothing after `await myTask()` you don't need to for it to stay on UI thread. For `myTask()` method, it will start running on the same thread than the caller. So it could depend on what you use many async call before with an ConfigureAwait(false). You must create a mental representation of your code" flow and try to find on each line on which thread you will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did try and it worked fine. I'm not sure if it has any other problem.

Some ASP.NET APIs work fine outside of their `SynchronizationContext`, and other's don't. Whether they need it or not is undocumented. I believe that the ones that work without the `SynchronizationContext` just *happen* to work without it; I don't believe they're designed with that use case in mind. Another consideration is that the ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext` ensures that only one thread runs at a time, so it synchronizes access to all the WebForms objects.

For these reasons, I always resume on the ASP.NET context before calling into any ASP.NET API. This includes setting WebForms properties. So I would not use `ConfigureAwait(false)` here.